# Show that $E_{n} + A^{T} A$ is non-singular.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that if $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, then $E_{n} + A^{T} A$ is a nonsingular matrix? ($E_{n}$ is a identity matrix.)

I tried thinking calculations of its elements, but I could not prove this.

Comment: The mattrix is definite symmetric therefore non-singular

Comment: Hint: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690078/positive-definite-matrix-plus-positive-semi-matrix-equals-positive-definite

Comment: Without invoking the PSD concept, you might approach it by induction on $n$, by writing $A = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider arbitrary $x\neq 0$. Then $x^{\text{T}}(I_n+A^TA)x=\underbrace{||x||^2}_{>0}+\underbrace{||Ax||^2}_{\ge 0}>0$ ergo the matrix is positive definite ergo regular.

Comment: Thank you so much! (It sounds like I shouldn't actually say)